# Getting places nearby for a city city and not for a specific latlng

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to get all the towns around a specific city (radius of 10km) without using a single pair of latlng?
I'd like to get all the towns around the city polygon in this radius (let's say there's a town in 8 km on the north, I can't just take the city center latlng and use it as it further than 10 km from this point).

How would you do it?

Thanks,
J.

I tried to use plcae_id instead of latlng but it id not work.

Answer (score -1):

with the google map API try this: (10km distance)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=**CITY_NAME**&radius=10000&types=(cities)&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You can take a look at this repository: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API

(edit) example request with a python script:

```
import requests

api_key = "API_KEY"
query = "[out:json];area[name='Istanbul'][admin_level=2]->.a;(node[place=town](area.a);way[place=town](area.a);relation[place=town](area.a));out body;>;out skel qt;"

response = requests.get(
    "https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/interpreter",
    params={
        "data": query,
        "key": api_key
    }
)

data = response.json()
```

Comment: Hi. thank you. I tried it and only got the city search results with no nearby cities.

Answer (score -1):

Using the Places API, you can request a nearby search of *x* radius from a center latitude/longitude literal **up to 50,000 meters**.

For example, using JavaScript, we fetch the nearby search API and use `(cities)` as the type parameter to use the collection of cities including towns, etc. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types for all the supported types.

`GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=API_KEY&location=-33.8670522%2C151.1957362&radius=8000&type=(cities)`

```js
const API_KEY = "API_KEY";

async function getNearbySearch(center, radius, type) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=${API_KEY}&location=${center.latitude}%2C${center.longitude}&radius=${radius}&type=${type}`);
    const result = await response.json();
    
    return result;
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
    
    return null;
  }
};

getNearbySearch({ latitude: -33.8670522, longitude: 151.1957362 }, 8000, "(cities)").then((nearbyCities) => {
  console.log(nearbyCities);
});
```

The response would look like: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#nearby-search-responses

Because of a bug with the `(cities)` type collection, we can instead query `locality` and `administrative_area_level_3` to combine the cities manually instead.

```js
const API_KEY = "API_KEY";

async function getNearbySearch(center, radius, type) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=${API_KEY}&location=${center.latitude}%2C${center.longitude}&radius=${radius}&type=${type}`);
    const result = await response.json();
    
    return result;
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
    
    return null;
  }
};

async function getNearbyCityCollectionSearch(center, radius) {
  const localityList = await getNearbySearch(center, radius, "locality");
  const administrativeAreaLevel3List = await getNearbySearch(center, radius, "administrative_area_level_3");
  
  return localityList.results.concat(administrativeAreaLevel3List.results);
};

getNearbyCityCollectionSearch({ latitude: -33.8670522, longitude: 151.1957362 }, 8000).then((nearbyCities) => {
  console.log(nearbyCities);
});
```

See this for the Places API documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But When I tried it I got *all* the places (hotels etc..) and not only cities. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What did you put in the type parameter? See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#type

Comment: I tried `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=${API_KEY}&location=32.07911174%2C34.77732566&radius=10000&type=(cities)`

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the collection. You can use `type=locality` or `type=administrative_area_level_3` instead until it's been patched by Google.

Comment: Yes. I also tried 'locality' but then I only got 2 cities (even when I used radius of 40 km). Something doesn't work...

Comment: I've opened a ticket at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/263154577 One solution for the moment could be querying both `locality` and `administrative_area_level_3` and combining the results. I've updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: "administrative_area_level_3" gives me a metropolitan area and not cities. "locality" returns only few cities but not nearly enough. Maybe the data in my country is the problem (but it's Google!). I don't know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It appears that the nearby search chooses to only return a limited amount of result, in the case of at least `type=locality` (in the cases I've tested, it limits the result to 2 anywhere).

Comment: @NoraSöderlund That would be because `type=locality` and `type=(cities)` is not supported by `Nearby Search`. Such types are only supported by Places Autocomplete and unfortunately, the expected result of OP is not possible using Places API atm.

Comment: Instead of a bug, I think it would be nice if we would file a Feature Request.

Comment: What does the `fetch` return? Have you tried running the code you provided in your answer?